# It shows java.lang.NullPointerException when i create another class for dialog

Tags: android

I create a sql database by SQLiteOpenHelper , i can update data completed.

It's about update `DatabaseHandler.java`:

```
//Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_DATE, contact.getDate());
    values.put(KEY_BMORNING, contact.getBeforeMorning());
    values.put(KEY_AMORNING, contact.getAfterMorning());
    values.put(KEY_BNOON, contact.getBeforeNoon());
    values.put(KEY_ANOON, contact.getAfterNoon());
    values.put(KEY_BNIGHT, contact.getBeforeNight());
    values.put(KEY_ANIGHT, contact.getAfterNight());

    //updating row
    Log.d("update:", String.valueOf(contact.getID()));
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {String.valueOf(contact.getID())});
}
```

I update the data by the code , it works:

```
//Contact is my jave bean class
db.updateContact(new Contact(id, choiceDate, choiceValue, "", "", "", "", ""));
```

I want to use dialog by another class , so i create it like this :

```
public class DialogHandler extends AppCompatActivity{

    private DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    private Context context;

    public DialogHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Alert dialog
    public void updateDialog(String rightMessage, String leftMessage, final Contact contact) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Data is existed")
                .setPositiveButton(rightMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        db.updateContact(contact);
                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(leftMessage, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

And then i change the update code like this:

```
new DialogHandler(this).updateDialog("Update", "Cancel", new Contact(id, choiceDate, choiceValue, "", "", "", "", ""));
```

It shows me the error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference`

and on this code `SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();`:

```
atcom.example.motogod19.testmysql1.DatabaseHandler.updateContact(DatabaseHandler.java:200)
```

How do i fix this error if i create `DialogHandler.java` for showing dialog ?  Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot to show us the relevant code inside `getWritableDatabase()`...

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i have paste it on my `updateContact` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DatabaseHandler` needs a context although you can only obtain the context in your constructor. Your IDE did not give you a warning because you extend the `DialogHandler` with `AppCompatActivity` which makes it flawed.

```
    private DatabaseHandler db = null;
    private Context context;

    public DialogHandler(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , i fix the problem by your suggestion , thanks again.